# Changing a number value using an inline assembly in C++

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I'm trying to increase a number value by using an inline assembly in C++. The reason that I do it that way is to practice my "inline assembly" skills.

Well that's what I've done so far:

```
void main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Please enter a number ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "The number you entered is: " << x << "\n";
    foo(&x);
    cout << "The new number is: " << x;
    cin >> x;
}

void foo(int *x) 
{
    __asm
    {
        inc [x]
    };
}
```

And the value never changed.

Comment: What compiler are you using? MSVC?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2012

Comment: You may want to disassemble the compiled code and see if it does what you expect. I've seen this sort of thing go wrong due to too little or too much indirection. You may be incrementing `x` rather than `*x`.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but does `inc DWORD PTR [x]` work?

Comment: @MatsPetersson how can I disassemble it?I know that it possible to disassemble only exe's and how can you say that I'm incrementing x rather then *x if I use the brackets?

Comment: @Cameron it doesn't work =\

Comment: @ImriPersiado `cl /Fa filename.cpp` will generate `filename.asm` which contains the assembly language listing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are incrementing the value of `x`, actually. `X` in terms of assembly language is a constant containing the address of `x` variable (of function `foo`). Which, in turn, contains the address of `main`'s `x`. So, `inc [x]` causes an increment of the pointer. You need to increment the value stored at the address `[x]`, like `inc [[x]]`. Of course you can not do it in one instruction in assembly language since you need *two* memory accesses: to know *where* the value is stored and to actually *increment* the value. So I'd advise a code like this:

```
push eax
mov eax, [x]
inc dword ptr [eax]
pop eax
```

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity I tried a different way based on your words: mov eax,x; mov ebx,[eax]; inc [ebx] and I faild, the value stays the same.

Comment: This is MSVC help to you. It automagically translates `mov eax, x` to the move of variable value. So, technically, you can replace the second line of my code with `mov eax, x`. 

In fact, this `x` for MSVC is just an index in stack frame. In pure assembly language you'd have to write `mov eax, [ebp + 8]` since x is the first stack variable. And in case you use `fastcall` calling convention, you'd write `inc [eax]`, just like that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's useful to know how Visual C++ increments the value of an int-pointer:

```
void foo(*x)
{
  (*x)++;
}
```

In debug mode, it is translated to

```
(*x)++;
mov         eax,dword ptr [x] 
mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax] 
add         ecx,1 
mov         edx,dword ptr [x] 
mov         dword ptr [edx],ecx
```

In release mode as same as Aneri's answer.

Answer (score -3):

x86 can only increment a register, not a memory, so you need move a pointer to a register. I ended with this:

```
__asm
{
    mov eax, x
    mov ebx, [eax]
    inc ebx
    mov [eax], ebx
};
```

Comment: Huh? Nonsense. `INC` can operate on register or memory operands.

Comment: That "works" because it adds an extra indirection. But `inc [eax]` would also work.

Comment: That the code "works" is irrelevant. I never said it didn't; indeed, I agree that the code he showed will do what he claims. What I meant is that it's nonsense that `INC` doesn't work on memory operands (aka pointers). http://www.negatory.com/ref/viewpage.php?key=inc

Comment: Hey. It happens to everyone. It's not a CISC architecture for nothing ;)